# How to restart a script from a specific point?

Tags: bash, if-statement, counter

Is there a way to make this script

```
#!/bin/bash

X=0

while true; do
    if [ $X -eq 10 ]; then
        sudo rm -r /var/log/daemon.log
        sudo rm -r /var/log/syslog
        sudo reboot
    fi

    expressvpn disconnect

    while timeout 2 ./typer; [ $? -eq 124 ]
    do
        exec $0
        let X++
    done
done
```

Restart from after the statement `X=0` if the command times out so that the counter doesn't reset? I'm using `exec $0` but it resets the counter every time I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `timer="${1-0}"` (default value of timer) and then `exec $0 "${timer}"` to keep the timer value in subsequent runs.

An additional advantage is that this enables you to easily test what happens when it times out - simply call it with a value of 10.

PS: To be on the safe side your `-eq` should be `-ge` (greater than or equal) in case a bug increases the timer by two.

Comment: Wait a minute I never used something like this... Do I have to keep the counter and just add these two lines or timer is like a new counter? Can you link me a manual or explain me what is "timer"?

Comment: It's just a rename of `X`. A better name would be `retries` or something.

Comment: Oh, ok I'll try

Comment: And what about the if condition? Should I change $X to $timer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to accomplish the same .
Create a flag file at the begining of the script and remove the file before ending the script.
And check for the flag condition whereever u would want the break.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: you can use if [ ! -f /tmp/abc.txt ]; then

Comment: Mmh... Nice solution, but it isn't the same as a counter since the first time it fails, the if condition comes true... I need 9 other timeouts before rebooting.